# Trying to boot Kali Linux from USB on Mid 2010 macbook pro

Tags: linux, boot, usb, grub, efi

I created a Kali Linux Live USB (MBR with compatibility for both BIOS+EFI) and created an /EFI/BOOT directory on the USB's root directory, with the file bootx64.efi in it. However, when I tried to boot into it, it said something about (hd0,1) not being found and that I need to start the kernel first... Any help?
If i'm being vague with what I did to make the USB, I followed these instructions: http://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?271-How-to-EFI-install-Kali-Linux

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the partition that says File System, find the boot folder and copy the `grub.cfg` file located there to your partition containing /EFI/BOOT/ into that very same folder that you have `bootx64.efi` and also from Fedora besides `bootx64.efi`. You need everything else from Fedora EFI folder besides the fonts folder. Try again and let me know how it goes.